# Multiple Swing Applet actionlisteners java

Tags: java, swing, applet

Is there a way to make all of these actionlisteners into one statement?

```
    jbtn0.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn1.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn2.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn3.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn4.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn5.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn6.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn7.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn8.addActionListener(this);
    jbtn9.addActionListener(this);
    jbtnAdd.addActionListener(this);


    jfrm.add(jbtn0);
    jfrm.add(jbtn1);
    jfrm.add(jbtn2);
    jfrm.add(jbtn3);
    jfrm.add(jbtn4);
    jfrm.add(jbtn5);
    jfrm.add(jbtn6);
    jfrm.add(jbtn7);
    jfrm.add(jbtn8);
    jfrm.add(jbtn9);
```

I am rather new to java, and I am using eclipse.

Comment: You could use an array of `JButton`'s and then iterate through it.

Comment: Yes, you could use an array or `List`, but you might also considering using `Action`s instead, see [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in a way. I do this sometimes:

```
for(JButton btn : new JButton[] {
    jbtn0, jbtn1, jbtn2, ... , jbtn9
}) {
    jbtn.addActionListener(this);
    jfrm.add(jbtn);
}
```

I do that even when my components do not start out in an array, for example if I am filling a JToolBar and need to refer to the components by name somewhere else.

Judging by your naming scheme, it may also be advantageous for you to use an array from the beginning.

Comment: this way getting a reference to a button doesn't even look very different: btn[0] as opposed to jbtn0

Answer (score -1):

As pzaenger said in his comment, you could add all your buttons into an ArrayList or an array, and then just iterate through all the entries and add an actionlistener to each one.